# Problem with time displayed by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

On some computers the time is displayed with a 1 plus (as if daylight saving time is active), and on other PCs the time is normal.

On computers that show the wrong time on the site, on the PC itself the time is right, but on the site it shows 1 hour more.

How can I fix this problem?

In Brazil daylight saving time was extinguished from this year.

HTML:

```
<input name="ANOATUAL" type="hidden" id="ANOATUAL" value="<?php echo date("Y"); ?>">
<input name="TIMEATUAL" type="hidden" id="TIMEATUAL" value="<?php echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); ?>">
<td id="relogio"></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
function iniciaCronometro(){

    var timeAgora = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TIMEATUAL").value);
    var anoAgora = document.getElementById("ANOATUAL").value;

    var myDate = new Date(timeAgora * 1000);
    var dataAtual = myDate.toLocaleString();

    var t = dataAtual.split(anoAgora);
    var horaAtual = trim(t[1]);

    var tempo = horaAtual.split(":");

    var h = tempo[0];
    var i = tempo[1];
    var s = tempo[2];

    document.getElementById("relogio").innerHTML = h+':'+i;
    document.getElementById("TIMEATUAL").value = (timeAgora + 1);

    setTimeout("iniciaCronometro()",1000);

}
```

Trim function:

```
function trim(str){
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

Comment: Why not use UTC time or a timestamp?

Comment: If you don't run the javascript function, what do the hidden fields contain on the right and wrong PCs?

Comment: Also, please add your trim() function to the question.

Comment: @blablabla I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @Frazer Trim function added..  In hidden fields the date appears correctly.

Comment: @zecaluis Maybe it's the toLocaleString()? Try toTimeString then split(":") then [0] is the hour and [1] the minute. You won't need anoAgora.

Comment: @Frazer Can you adjust in pastebin? My knowledge of javascript is a bit limited.

Comment: try to set using $datel = new DateTime('', new DateTimeZone('BRAZIL REGION')); echo $datel->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: @zecaluis Have added an answer with javascript alternative. (What's pastebin?)

Comment: It looks like the problem is in `strtotime();` of the hidden fields. Ex timestamp: https://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=2&timestamp=1573750609&Submit=++++++Convert+to+Date++++++ | Print: https://nimb.ws/yaCbPs | The correct would be 13:56:49

Comment: @zecaluis Why is the correct 13:56:49 when you are inputting 14:56:49?

Comment: @Frazer He is generating this Timestamp with an extra hour, I did not put it.

Comment: @zecaluis I'm confused. 1. What time is on the server? 2. What time do you want displayed on the PCs? 3. Try an input field with `<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>` and no javascript. Does it show the time you want?

Comment: 4. Does the comment from @redhatvicky solve this?

Comment: On the server the time is correct, in case 13:56:49. I need to display this time in html, the exact time of the server. I tried the @redhatvicky hint, it prints the correct time in the hidden field, the problem occurs when javascript updates the value in html, it is adding an extra time to the server time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202360/discussion-between-frazer-and-zecaluis).

Comment: Is it adding extra time, or is it displaying the time in the user's time zone rather than the server's time zone? time zones don't change what time it is, they simply alter the way it is displayed.

Comment: @Kevin, yes exactly, it is displaying the time in the user's time zone rather than the server's time zone.

Comment: Then `toLocaleString` is probably the wrong method to use.

Comment: eh, well, it's the right method, but you need to give it parameters so that it presents the date using the same time-zone settings your server is using. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: @Kevin Do you think it is possible to integrate this into my current script?

Comment: Yes, i believe that would be very possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_dates.html) brilliant book suggests "Best practice: avoid the built-in Date"!

As we have discussed in chat, the following works for you.

HTML:

```
  <td id="relogio" data-server-time="<?php echo date('Y,m,d,H,i,s'); ?>"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
let agoraValue = 0;

const doDom = () => {
  const relogio = document.querySelector("#relogio");
  const b = relogio.getAttribute("data-server-time").split(",");
  const agora = new Date(b[0], (b[1]-1), b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
  agoraValue = agora.valueOf();
  setInterval(iniciaCronometro,1000);
};

const iniciaCronometro = () => {
  const myDate = new Date(agoraValue);
  const h = myDate.getHours();
  const i = ("0" + String(myDate.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
  const timeAgora = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TIMEATUAL").value);
  relogio.innerHTML = h+':'+i;
  document.getElementById("TIMEATUAL").value = (timeAgora + 1);
  agoraValue = agoraValue + 1000;
};

// Await DOM to be loaded
if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    doDom();
  });
} else {
  doDom();
}
```

Comment: What does the whole script look like? I tried to implement but it didn't work, see: https://pastebin.com/yqfhn8Dq

Comment: It looks like the problem is in `strtotime();` of the hidden fields. Ex timestamp: https://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=2&timestamp=1573750609&Submit=++++++Convert+to+Date++++++ | Print: https://nimb.ws/yaCbPs | The correct would be 13:56:49

Comment: Try the `new Date()` option.

Comment: It doesn't work. :/ It just synced with my computer time, but still added an extra hour.

This option should be discarded because I need to sync with the server time, not the local computer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Can you answer me a question in chat? Thx :)

Answer (score -1):

Can i advice you to use a library which will solve you most problems and time consumed with parsing/formatting/etc of dates and times ?

https://momentjs.com/

If you do not want to use it, you should always use an international time/date standard then create custom functions for formatting for each country/language you want to render to.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how to implement this in my script. It seems to be something interesting.